# Why is a new child being created, under my database when trying to update a child value?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update my quantity child value inside my Firebase database, and whenever attempting to do so a new child is created instead of the current value being updated. As seen in the screenshot a new UID with the quantity 2 is being generated when it should update the current quantity instead. I am not sure why this is happening can someone assist me with this. I attached an image of how my database is structured,

```
loggedInUID: U4Rc9hD6WHUC5vjqCezclsqKdcr2
tappedonimagetimestamp: U4Rc9hD6WHUC5vjqCezclsqKdcr2 00:20:44
```

[image: Database]

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
    holder.produceName.setText(cartArrayList.get(position).getProductName());
    Log.i("productname", cartArrayList.get(position).getProductName());

    holder.producePrice.setText("$" + cartArrayList.get(position).getItemPrice());
    holder.plusImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("produtUID", cartArrayList.get(position).getTimestamp());

            getCurrentUserUid();


            count = count + 1;
            holder.middleQUanityTv.setText(count + "");

            Log.i("tappedonimagetimestamp", cartArrayList.get(position).getTimestamp());
            Log.i("loggedInUID", loggedInUserId);


            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cart").child(loggedInUserId).child(cartArrayList.get(position).getTimestamp()).child("quantity").setValue(count);


        }
    });


    //Log.i("IMAGES", productArrayList.get(position).getProductImage());
    Glide.with(ct)
            .load(cartArrayList.get(position).getProductImage())
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.productImage);


}


public void addItemToCart(){

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" HH:mm:ss ");
    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    timeStamp = loggedInUserId + formatter.format(date);



    userDictionary.put("itemPrice", selectedPrice.trim());
    userDictionary.put("productname",productNameText.trim());
    userDictionary.put("description", selectedStringProductDescrtipon.trim());
    userDictionary.put("uid",loggedInUserId.trim());
    userDictionary.put("productImage", selectedImage.trim());
    userDictionary.put("datee",date.toString());
    userDictionary.put("name",loggedInUserName.trim());
    userDictionary.put("timestamp",timeStamp.trim());
    userDictionary.put("time",formatter.format(date).trim());
    userDictionary.put("quantity","1");



    uploadPostRef.child("Cart").child(loggedInUserId).child(timeStamp).setValue(userDictionary).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
            Log.i("sucessfully added","sucesssfully added to cart..");
            getLoggedInUserData();

        }
    });
    numberInCartIv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


}
```

Comment: Are you sure that no where else in the code is there any hook that's trying to update the document? This happened to me once because I was doing an incorrect update.

Comment: Please edit the question to be clear exactly what you are expecting this code, and how it's different than what you're observing.  It's pretty clear that you're building the path incorrectly, but we can't seen any of the values of variables in your code, nor can we see the full path of the child you're trying to update.

Comment: I updated my question, what do you mean by any hook?

Comment: Obviously your id didnt match. Can you share how did you store for the first time into cart?

Comment: It does match from what's being displayed from the log

Comment: I updated my question, that's how I stored the item to the cart

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was this, when I was adding the items to my cart, I used the trim method at the end of every value. I simply removed this and then ran my code and everything was working fine.